# find word before second comma with regex

Tags: php, regex, string

I want to store the word before the second comma in a string.

So if the string looks like this: Hello, my name is David, bla bla.

I want to set a variable $test = David

Answer (score 13, accepted):

```
^[^,]*,[^,]*\b(\w+)\b,
```

`^` -- The beginning of the string/line
`[^ ]` -- Any character not being ...
`,` -- ... a comma
`*` -- Zero or more of the preceding
`,` -- A comma
`[^,]*` -- Again, any character not being a comma, repeated zero or more times
`\b` -- A word boundary (zero width)
`( )` -- A capturing group
`\w` -- Any word character
`+` -- One or more of the preceding
`\b` -- A word boundary (zero width)
`,` -- A comma

Answer (score 5):

Your regex could look something like this:

```
^[^,]*,[^,]*\b(\w+),
```

Match any sequence of non-commas, followed by the first comma, followed by more non-commas, then a word boundary and your actual word, and then the second comma.

Comment: word boundary is `\b` - `\w` is word itself

Comment: `\w` is a word character, not a word boundary.  `[^,]` is any character that is not a comma, not a word character.

Comment: also you might wanna consider capturing `(\w+)` instead of `([^,]*)` as the later matches even an empty string. When tested with Expresso, this regex matched the word boundary and empty string after David.

Comment: You're right. Now it's nearly the same as Svante's solution, which I upvoted anyway because his explanation is much nicer.

Answer (score 2):

this is web based nice tool which name is **[txt2re](http://www.txt2re.com)**

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php

    $s = "Hello, my name is David, bla bla.";

    preg_match ( "/[^,]*,[^,].* ([^,].*),.*/" , $s, $matches ); 

    // or shorter ..
    preg_match ( "/[^,]*,[^,]*\b(\w+),/" , $s, $matches );

    echo $matches[1];
    // => David

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$s = "Hello, my name is David, bla bla.";
$s = explode(',', $s);
$s = explode(' ', $s[1]);
$test = $s[sizeof($s)-1];

print $test;
'David'
```

Answer (score 0):

And here is my approach:

```
<?php
    $input  = 'Hello, my name is David, bla bla.';
    $tmp    = substr( $input, 0, strpos( $input, ',', strpos( $input, ',' ) + 1 ) );
    $word   = substr( $tmp, strrpos( $tmp, ' ' ) + 1 );
    echo $word;
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Hokay, I know this is old, but I'm practicing…

How about `/,.*?(\w+),/`?

There's a saved explanation at this excellent tool: http://regex101.com/r/yA4gN5

- `,` matches the character , literally
- `.*?` matches any character (except newline)

  - Quantifier: Between zero and unlimited times, as few times as possible, expanding as needed [lazy]
- 1st Capturing group `(\w+)`

  - `\w+` match any word character [a-zA-Z0-9_]
  - Quantifier: Between one and unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed [greedy]
- `,` matches the character , literally

This regex (and some above) fails if David enters a non word character after his name, so 
'David!,' and 'David ,' both fail.